# How to set color of only the clicked IconButton - ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I am new to React JS. I have multiple IconButtons. OnClick I want only the clicked button to change its color. I have used state but when state changes, the color of all buttons change. What approach should I apply? Is there a way to change color without using state? Is there need of a key or id?
The code I have provided is cropped  (means it only contains parts I think are relevant).

```
class Utilitybar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bgColor: "default"
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IconButton color={
          this.state.bgColor
        }
          onClick={
            () => {
              this.props.vidToggle();
              if (this.state.bgColor === "default") {
                this.setState({ bgColor: "primary" })
              } else {
                this.setState({ bgColor: "default" })
              }
            }
          }>
          <FaPlayCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton color={
          this.state.bgColor
        }
          onClick={
            () => {
              this.props.fileToggle();
              if (this.state.bgColor === "default") {
                this.setState({ bgColor: "primary" })
              } else {
                this.setState({ bgColor: "default" })
              }
            }
          }>
          <FaRegFileAlt />
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect only clicked button to change color. But obviously they all use the same state, and when state is changed then the color of all buttons is changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of storing a shared property (bg color), store the information you really need : i.e. the pressed button

```
class Utilitybar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onButtonClicked = this.onButtonClicked.bind(this)
    this.state = { currentButton: null }
  }

  onButtonClicked (id) {
    this.setState({ currentButton: this.state.currentButton === id ? null : id })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <IconButton
          color={this.state.currentButton === 0 ? "primary" : "default" }
          onClick={() => this.onButtonClicked(0)}>
          <FaPlayCircle/>
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton
          color={this.state.currentButton === 1 ? "primary" : "default" }
          onClick={() => this.onButtonClicked(1)}>
          <FaRegFileAlt/>
        </IconButton>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

edit: the idea is to store an ID corresponding to one of your buttons (note that I assumed only one button can be clicked at a time). This ID is put in the component state. Then each button will check its ID against the ID in the state; if it match then it will render a different background.
Since you probable want the button to be unpressed after a second click, the onButtonClicked checks the current ID before updating the state, and if it is the same as the new one, it clears the stored ID instead

Comment: Can you explain the working of onButtonClicked function?

Comment: what if I want multiple buttons to be clicked at a time? Like, clicking on a button will not clear the set color of previously clicked button. What change would I need in the code? Thanks.

Comment: store an array of id in the state instead of a single ID